# Compressing single file instead of whole directory

Tags: tar

Hi guys i've been trying for hours to get my script working, the issue is that instead of compressing a single file, it compresses the whole directory structure.

```
    #!/bin/sh

# Where to backup to.
mkdir -p /home/knoppix/backups --verbose
dest="/home/knoppix/backups"

# What to backup.
cat /etc/passwd >> /home/knoppix/backups/dbusers.txt
backupdb="/home/knoppix/backups/dbusers.txt"

# Create archive filename.
archive_file="DB$(date +%d%b%Y_%H%M).tgz"

# Print start status message.
echo "Backing up $backupdb to $dest/$archive_file"
date
echo

# Backup the files using tar.
tar czf $dest/$archive_file $backupdb
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using tar -C to move into the directory:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Where to backup to.
mkdir -p /home/knoppix/backups --verbose
dest="/home/knoppix/backups"

# What to backup.
cat /etc/passwd >> /home/knoppix/backups/dbusers.txt
backupdir="/home/knoppix/backups"
backupfile="dbusers.txt"

# Create archive filename.
archive_file="DB$(date +%d%b%Y_%H%M).tgz"

# Print start status message.
echo "Backing up $backupdb to $dest/$archive_file"
date
echo

# Backup the files using tar.
tar czf $dest/$archive_file -C $backupdir $backupfile
```

GNU tar also provides a `--transform` option, which can be used to tweak the name for archive creation or extraction. Another way to change your original script would be to do something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Where to backup to.
mkdir -p /home/knoppix/backups --verbose
dest="/home/knoppix/backups"

# What to backup.
cat /etc/passwd >> /home/knoppix/backups/dbusers.txt
backupdir="/home/knoppix/backups"
backupfile="dbusers.txt"

# Create archive filename.
archive_base_name="DB$(date +%d%b%Y_%H%M)"
archive_file="$archive_base_name.tgz"

# Print start status message.
echo "Backing up $backupdb to $dest/$archive_file"
date
echo

# Backup the files using tar.
tar --transform="s#^$base#$archive_base_name#" czPf $dest/$archive_file $backupdb
```

The argument to `--transform` says to substitute one string of text for another, like `s#old#new#`. The `old` portion is actually a pattern called a regular expression, and `^` will cause the regex to match only at the beginning of a line. And the `P` (in `czPf`) tells tar not to remove the '/' from the beginning of paths. So in this example, the tar will be created with something like:

```
DB11Nov2011_0555/dbusers.txt
```

If you have an existing archive containing a file named like "dbusers.txt", you can use `--transform` to extract it to another name or directory:

```
tar --transform="s#dbusers#original#" xzf example.tgz # creates original.txt
tar --transform="s#^#output/#" xzf example.tgz        # creates output/dbusers.txt
```

Try adding `v` to the tar options (`czPvf`) to get it to display the names of files as they are being added or extracted. When using `--transform`, it might also help to use `--show-transformed-names` so that the `v` flag shows the results of the substitution instead of the original names.

Finally, for a bit more troubleshooting help, try adding `set -x` at the top of the script (or just before the `tar` command). It will cause the shell to print a command before executing it. The useful part is that it will show the *values* used, after variables and wildcards are evaluated.

You can even try this on the command line. Use `set +x` to turn if back off:

```
$ set -x
$ archive_file="DB$(date +%d%b%Y_%H%M).tgz"
++ date +%d%b%Y_%H%M
+ archive_file=DB11Nov2011_0605.tgz
$ echo $archive_file
+ echo DB11Nov2011_0605.tgz
DB11Nov2011_0605.tgz
$ set +x
+ set +x
$ echo $archive_file
DB11Nov2011_0605.tgz
```

Comment: This one also works like a charm, When i extract the tar it just extracts the file, is there anyway to make it extract a folder then the file inside

Comment: Absolutely! I've updated the post to show the use of --transform for archive creation and extraction.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
# Backup the files using tar.
(cd /home/knoppix/backups/; tar czf $dest/$archive_file dbusers.txt)
```

Comment: It did the trick! thankss i tried doing cd "$dest" but it didnt work, thanks alot finally i can move on

Comment: one more little thing when i uncompress the zip it just extracts the file inside, is there anyway it can uncompress the folder then the file inside